# Android - Release resources when starting a call

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-audiorecord

in my app I use audio record and mic to record anything, but i need to release it for incoming and outcoming call.
For incoming I have use a BroadcastReceiver class, but for outcoming ?
I can't release in onPause or others method of my app because the audio record is inside a service (background).
I need to recognize when the user starts a call.

Answer (score 0):

release it in `onDestroy()` of your Service

Comment: I can't because I need to stop ONLY if a call incoming or outcoming

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Actually, I believe your app will automatically stop recording once you start calling someone. Usually, that's what developers are complaining about, that the api doesn't let them record phone calls (unless they use undocumented apis). This is the first time I hear of someone complaining about the reverse happening.

Comment: I need to release resources like mic because it need to call